# Which Play Service Libraries for Google Tag Manager

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-tag-manager

I want to integrate Google Tag Manager v4 into my app. In the tutorial it just says "Set up the Google Play Services SDK". I don't want to add the complete Services SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2) but only the libraries I really need. 
Here is the list of the available libraries:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#Install

Question:
Does anyone of you know which google play service libraries I need to get Google Tag Manager running?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding only the following

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2'
}
```